# How can third-party apps be set as system apps on Redmi Note 11 running MIUI 14?

Tags: rooting, xiaomi, system-apps, redmi-note-11

I'm thinking about turning this third-party app into a system app. It has some great functionalities that could benefit  me. Can you help me understand the process

Comment: On stock device you can not make an app a system app. Only the manufacturer can do that by signing the app appropriately. Also regular apps have no advantage in being installed as system app as you need to consider extended permissions available to system apps have when developing the app.